# Find a rise and fall in continuosly publishing data

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, data-analysis

Hi I have a series of intensity data being published. What is the best way (most efficient) to find an abrupt rise and fall in the data using Python? Data gets published continuously and looks like the following :

```
11433
12899
12134
4399
11003
12001
```

Comment: Use ```np.diff``` and check for some threshold value (?)

Comment: Looking at the source code, ```np.diff``` is just an abstraction of using ```np.subtract``` on consecutive elements. In your scenario it would probably be better to use ```np.subtract``` directly and specify the ```out``` keyword to prevent superfluous memory allocation. Then take the absolute (or square) of the difference and check for extreme values, which can be done conveniently with a boolean mask.

Comment: Create a fixed length deque https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque with 3, 5 or 9 elements and push each new sample in, forcing oldest sample off the other end, and see if this one is too far from the mean/stddev of the others.